# Cant see client secret in application credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have an application for Windows in C# and i wanted to connect to Google calendar. In the tutorials and documentation example [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate) they require some client secret which is to be generated when requesting client ID for a service account. But it's not. However I can see the public key fingerprints and I installed a certificate that was generated when I requested the client ID.

My guess is that their documentation is outdated. Can anyone give me a tutorial/reference or explain how this is should work now?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I used Google Calendar API you did not need a Client Secret for Oauth Service Account authorization. You just need Application ID, private key and the service account email address if I am right. I used it with java, but here is an example for .NET if it can help you.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (OAuth 2.0), the token endpoint of OAuth 2.0 authorization server requires **[client authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2.1)** in the following cases.

1. The [client type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) of the client application is **confidential**.
2. The [client type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) of the client application is **public** but the client application has been issued client credentials (`client_id` + `client_secret`).

To put it the other way around, **client authentication is not required (so `client_secret` is not needed) when the client type of the client application is public and the client application has not been issued client credentials.**

By definition, a public client cannot keep its client credentials confidential. Therefore, in general, implementations of OAuth 2.0 authorization servers won't issue a client secret for public client applications. It sounds that Google's implementation behaves so, too.

Probably, the reason Google did not issue a client secret to your application was that the client configuration you choiced had made your client application a public client.

The public key fingerprint is a different matter. RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0) does not mention anything about public keys. Instead, I guess it may be related to [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), [OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html) (especially `token_endpoint_auth_method`), or [Assertion Framework for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-assertions). You have to read Google's document to know what the public key fingerprint is for.

Comment: Great, but the function in API for .NET to connect to calendar requires it. I cant just skip it. Or if I can, I'd like to see a doc or tutorial or a blogpost on it as a guide. Or an example below would be nice. Thanks